# error while executing sonar with ant file

Tags: ant, sonarqube

the lines below are the start of my ant build file and when i try and implemnet sonar with it it shows following error.

The value of attribute "xmlns:sonar" associated with an element type "project" must not contain the '<' character.

```
      <project name="DokLink"  default="all"  basedir="." xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant>

      <description> Build the DevEnvExample, to illustrate how DevEnv works </description>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have submitted an invalid XML file to ANT. You're missing an end quote around the Sonar URI:

```
$ xmllint build.xml
..
..
build.xml:3: namespace error : xmlns:sonar: 'antlib:org.sonar.ant>        ' is not a valid URI
..
..
```

The following is a corrected XML file:

```
<project name="DokLink"  default="all"  basedir="." xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">

      <description> Build the DevEnvExample, to illustrate how DevEnv works </description>

</project>
```